# Scroll controller direction not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to execute a function whenever i am scrolling down and also whenever I am scrolling up under certain conditions but not working.

The code below is always printing down to the console even when I am scrolling up
NB: searchBarHeight = 30;

```
void onListenableCall() {
    setState(() {
      if (controller.hasClients) {
        final offset = controller.offset;
        final axisDirection = controller.position.axisDirection;
        if (axisDirection == AxisDirection.down && offset < searchBarHeight) {
          print('down');
        }
        else if (axisDirection == AxisDirection.up && offset < searchBarHeight) {
          print('up');
          pinChatText = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after reading the docs, this can be achieved by a property called userScrollDirection

```
void onListenableCall() {
    setState(() {
      if (controller.hasClients) {
        final offset = controller.offset;
        final scrollDirection = controller.position.userScrollDirection;
        if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse && offset < searchBarHeight) {
          print('down');
        }
        else if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward && offset < searchBarHeight) {
          print('up');
          pinChatText = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```